# QGIS plugin, GeoSearch: Doesn't Search

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to use the QGIS plugin GeoSearch. Every time I type in an address and hit search, nothing happens. When I first installed it a few months back, it worked like a charm, I dont know why one day it just wouldn't work. I have a valid google API because I use google basemap layers every day.

Things I've tried:
-I've uninstalled/reinstalled
-When I use the 'Search On Google Web Map' feature, It opens to the address immediately
-tried different Geocoders with no response.

[image: geosearch plugin]

QGIS version : 2.14.10-Essen
OS: Windows 7 64-bit edition

Comment: The plugin's V3 geocoder appears to support custom API keys but the plugin GUI doesn't appear to provide any way of providing these, so it'll be using a demo API key (or no API key at all). Have you seen any way of providing your API key at all? This might need some Python hacking on your local plugin installation to work.

Comment: I ended up downloaded the plugin OSMsearch to replace Geosearch. I'm afraid my antiquated version of QGIS might be to blame. Thanks for answering @StevenKay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to edit googlev3.py and google.py in order to set the variable secret_key after activating billing in Google Cloud Platform / Geocoging API, but nothing is happening. It seems this very good plugin is now deprecated. We hope somebody correct it and reach to migrate it to QGIS 3.x

Comment: i think you're right. I'm now using the Experimental plug in, OSM place search

Answer (score 1):

In case you're always searching a set of the same places, the QGIS functionality "**spatial bookmark**" might help out. It's not a plugin to search places as GeoSearch, but I am now using it instead to quickly relocate to places I've once searched (and marked with a bookmark).

Comment: wow I didn't know about that, thanks!